# How can I render a twig template in a custom controller in Silex?

Tags: view, controller, twig, render, silex

I'm playing with Silex microframework to build a very simple app.
The Silex documentation briefly illustrates how to keep your code organised using controller as class and I've also found this useful article talking about the same practice:
https://igor.io/2012/11/09/scaling-silex.html 
but still can't solve my problem

**The issue:**

in my app.php I'm using

```
$app->get('/{artist}', 'MyNamespace\\MyController::getAlbum');
```

This is working. MyController is a class correctly loaded through composer using psr-4. 
At the moment the return method of getAlbum($artist) is `return $player;`
What I'd like to do instead, is returning a twig view from getAlbum, something like:

```
return $app['twig']->render('player.twig', $player);
```

To do so, what I've tried to do in my custom class/controller is:

```
use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
[...]
        public function getAlbum(Request $request, Application $app, $artist)
```

but this is generating the following error when I try to access the routed pages:

```
ReflectionException in ControllerResolver.php line 43:
Class MyNamespace\Request does not exist
```

Whic made me think that there's a namespace conflict between myNamespace and the Silex namespaces?!

What am I doing wrong?
Is this the right way to make $app visible in my custom controller in order to use return $app['twig']... ?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

After several other tries still didn't get to the point (replies still welcome!) but I've found a workaround solution that could be useful to anyone will incur in a similar issue. Directly in my app.php I added this

```
$app->get('/{artist}', function (Silex\Application $app, $artist) use ($app)
{ 
 $object = new MyNamespace\MyController(); 
 $player = $object->getAlbum($artist); 
 return $app['twig']->render('player.twig', 
  array( 
    //passing my custom method return to twig
   'player' => $player,)); 
});
```

then in my player.twig I added:

```
    {{player | raw}}
```

And this basically means that I still need an anonymous function to get use of my custom method which is a working solution I'm not really happy with because:

- I'm using 2 functions for 1 purpose.
- The return value of getAlbum is dependent from the use of "raw" in twig.

**SOLVED**

The workflow described works fine. It was a distraction error: I've placed the namespace of my custom class after     use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
namespace declaration in PHP needs always to be at the top of the file, Silex wasn't able to injects $app and $request for this reason.

Comment: This all looks fine to me. The namespace imports for `Request` and `Application` are correct, and also the way you try to render the view. But what surprises me is that (if I understand correctly) you get the error *only* when trying to return `return $app['twig']->render(...)`, not with `return $player` – and that is something I cannot really believe, as the problem is obviously caused by the function parameter, not the return value. BTW: I’d suggest appending the suffix “Action” to the names of all action methods in a container.

Comment: Is it possible that in *MyMamespace* you have a Request class? Can you fully paste your controller class?

Comment: @BlueM not exactly, the error comes as long as I try to pass Request $request, Application $app, I've now tried to do the following **directly in myapp.php** which is working for my case (but still can't understand why the above method isn't working): `$app->get('/{artist}', function (Silex\Application $app, $artist)  use ($app){
 $object = new MyNamespace\MyController();
 $player = $object->getAlbum($artist);
 return $app['twig']->render('player.twig', array( 
  'player' => $player,  
 ));
});` and then just {{player | raw}} in my twig

Comment: @mTorres nope no Request class in my namespace:

Comment: ok, what version of silex are you using? It should autodetect the request paremeter and inject it (see [here](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/ControllerResolver.php#L50) and [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php#L115)).

Comment: @mTorres composer is set like so: "silex/silex": "~1.2",

Comment: my advice is to delete the vendor folder and reinstall the dependencies (```composer install```). If that does not work, can you fully paste your controller class?

Comment: The namespace of my custom class was placed after Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; moving it to the very top of course solved the problem ... thanks anyway for all the answers